# Bootstrap columns have to move to the side when there is room

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, xhtml

I want to make a dictionary in HTML, so I want to have a div with class: 'col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1' for every character.

But when I have for example A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and B contains lots of words
the D, E, F will be placed at the bottom, below the B.

Example code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="dropcap">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Some word</h4>
        <span>some explanation</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="dropcap">B</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Some word</h4>
        <span>some explanation</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="dropcap">C</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Some word</h4>
        <span>some explanation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Some word</h4>
        <span>some explanation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Some word</h4>
        <span>some explanation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Some word</h4>
        <span>some explanation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Some word</h4>
        <span>some explanation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Some word</h4>
        <span>some explanation</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="dropcap">D</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Some word</h4>
        <span>some explanation</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="dropcap">E</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Some word</h4>
        <span>some explanation</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="dropcap">F</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Some word</h4>
        <span>some explanation</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to have it like this:

[image: This is seems really hard to achieve]

I am really stuck at this moment..

Comment: Can you show us some code and possibly a demo. ta

Comment: I've added the code, it's quite straight-forward, just the column classes from bootstrap. My live problem can be found here: http://jdev.dartcounter.nl/info/dictionary

Comment: @Jason, I have edited and posted correct solution. check below.

Comment: It seems bootstrap won't resolve this issue. You need to use jquery. There is a solution jquery nested: http://suprb.com/apps/nested/  Try to use it.

Comment: @Banzay that's not what I want, becaus if 'E' fits better under 'A', and 'D' fits better under 'C' you'll get A, B, C, E, D etc.

Comment: I didn't find any good solutions, so I decided to change the layout..

Comment: I made a solution with jquery. if you interested to find out, I can show it.

Comment: @Banzay I can do that too, but I preferred a non-javascript solution :)

Comment: With css only It would be a real magic

Answer (score 0):

I have the edited and re posted. Try this.

```js
// to update mobile screen
function mobile(){
          $('#A').appendTo($('#col1'));
            $('#B').appendTo($('#col1'));
            $('#C').appendTo($('#col1'));
            $('#D').appendTo($('#col1'));
            $('#E').appendTo($('#col1'));
            $('#F').appendTo($('#col1'));
  }
  $(function() {
        var w = $(window).width();
        // called for mobile users
        if (w < 768 ) {
              mobile();
           
        }
        
    // for browser resizes
          $(window).resize(function() {
               var rw = $(window).width();
                if (rw < 768 ) {
                       mobile();
                }
                 else{
                      $('#B').appendTo($('#col2'));
                      $('#C').appendTo($('#col3'));
                      $('#E').appendTo($('#col3'));
                      $('#D').appendTo($('#col1'));
                      $('#F').appendTo($('#col1'));
              } 
    });
});
```

```css
h3{
text-align:center;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4" id="col1">
                  <div   style="background:red;" id="A">
                      <h3>A</h3><br /><br /> <br /><br /><br />
                  </div>
                  
                  <div   style="background:orange;" id="D">
                      <h3>D</h3><br /> <br /><br /><br />
                  </div>
                 
                  <div  style="background:grey;" id="F">
                      <h3>F</h3><br /> <br /><br /><br />
                  </div>
                  
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4" id="col2" >
                 <div   style="background:green;" id="B">
                      <h3>B</h3><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4" id="col3">
                  <div  style="background:Yellow;" id="C">
                      <h3>C</h3><br /> <br /><br /><br />
                  </div>
                  
                  <div   style="background:violet;" id="E">
                      <h3>E</h3> <br /> <br /><br /><br />
                  </div>
                  
              </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: That's not what I want. When you watch this on a smaller screen and the divs will go below eachother you will get:
A, D, F, B, C, E, That's why the div's need to stay in alphabetical order. Also I don't want to change the positions of those divs by hand, when there are words added.

Comment: @jason i understood the problem. I will edit and post it back.

Comment: @jason, I have edited and posted back check the solution. I hope u like the solution.

Comment: It's okay, I would still prefer looking at the height of the other divs and then append a character if it is shorter. But I was looking if it was possible with css, I guess not :(